# Data type conversion of column in numpy record array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, record

I have a numpy recarray with several integer columns and some string columns. The data in the string columns is composed 99% of integers, but numpy things it's a string because "NA" is in the column.

So I have two questions:

- How do I remove the NA's and change them to 0s?
- How can I convert the string columns to integers so that I can have a record array with many integer columns?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `where` and `astype`:

```
>>> x = np.array([123, 456, "789", "NA", "0", 0])
>>> x 
array(['123', '456', '789', 'NA', '0', '0'], dtype='|S8')
>>> np.where(x != 'NA', x, 0).astype(int)
array([123, 456, 789,   0,   0,   0])
```

Comment: This works great on nd arrays, but how do I keep the "rec"-ness of the record array i'm using? Sry, i didn't make it clear earlier that I was using a rec array

Comment: You can add a new column to a rec array with the help of `rec_append_fields` from [`matplotlib.mlib`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/mlab_api.html) (see section "Record array helper functions"). Perhaps adding a new column with new data and removing the old column is the simplest if not the only possible way to achieve the desired results.

Comment: It took me an incredibly long time of confusion to realize that the [19>, [20>, and [21> were your prompt.

Comment: Another possibility is using [`fromrecords`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.core.records.fromrecords.html) to build a new recarray from the original, doing the transformation per record.